# IO Output different from expected

Tags: c#, io

I have a .txt file that contains:

```
123456
45789
check
check
```

I want to replace `check` to `now`, I wrote the following code but the result was not as I expected:

```
123456
45789
now
nowheck
```

I wonder why the last line became `nowheck`.

My code:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\jzhu\Desktop\test1.txt"));
string fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
fileContent = fileContent.Replace("check", "now");
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Users\jzhu\Desktop\test1.txt"));
writer.Write(fileContent);
writer.Close();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `File.OpenWrite` is reopening the same file for writing *without truncating it first*.

You could use `File.Create` instead, or better yet use the methods which make reading and writing text simple:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\jzhu\Desktop\test1.txt";
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(path);
fileContent = fileContent.Replace("check", "now");
File.WriteAllText(path, fileContent);
```

Comment: can you explain what you mean by truncating it first?

Comment: @HashMap: Basically starting a new file, rather than just overwriting *some* of the bits of the old flie.

Comment: you are missing a left bracket at `@"C:\Users\jzhu\Desktop\test1.txt");`, code works perfectly

Comment: @HashMap: Rather, I had an extra `)` at the end - that was unnecessary. Removed now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`File.OpenWrite` is reopening the same file.
To avoid that problem, try with `File.Create`

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the output to a second file. It should be correct. The problem is that the original content is still there. You need to truncate the file when opening it the second time.

Comment: that would be pretty inefficient in my opinion it's more efficient to read all the text into a varialble then within the context of the read replace occurrences of the word `check` with `now`

Comment: and how to get it back to disk? that is the issue, not the replacing part... Jon Skeets solution is the best way to go!

Comment: why are you asking something when you proposed something but did not at the very least suggest a coded solution what you have written would work.. but in my opinion it's useless since you did not provide the OP with a coded solution as an alternative.. and yes I am quite aware that Jon Skeets solutions is the best ... cheers...!